# Zorin 9 installation hangs at Install Zorin alongside Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition

Tags: system-installation, zorin

I want to install Zorin 9 alongside Windows XP, but the installation hangs at this step. I also tried the `nomodeset` option, but it didn't work.

[image]